# Postgres Error with regex for finding phone numbers, ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am trying to find phone numbers that fit into the following regex in postgres on one particular field. Im getting the error ERROR: invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid but not sure why. It seems like legitimate regex but fails when I try to run.

```
~'^([0-9]( |-)?)?(\\(?[0-9]{3}\\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$'
```

Any help would be great!

Ive tried escaping the | but it didn't seem to help. Tried looking at other questions on here on regex but haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Have a look: https://regex101.com/r/1g1s1n/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a single `\` to escape the parentheses

```sql
select '123 456-7890' ~'^([0-9]( |-)?)?(\(?[0-9]{3}\)?|[0-9]{3})( |-)?([0-9]{3}( |-)?[0-9]{4}|[a-zA-Z0-9]{7})$';
 ?column?
----------
 t
(1 row)
```